# How to display total value of dropdown select boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to sum up all values in dropdown select boxes from duplicated forms.

Javascript Code (Gives me the count but it's not working as it should).

```
<script>
function onChange(elem) { 
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks + Number(elem.value);    
    };
</script>
```

HTML (Button to duplicate a form)

```
<div class="card-header">
<h4 class="request-title">
    Request Temps
    <button onClick="onClick()">ADD</button>
</h4>
    <p class="request">Number <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
</div>
```

Main form

```
<form action="<?php echo '/request-temp/'; ?>" method="post">
<div class="col7">
<div class="form-group mb-2">
        <label>Select Repetition</label> <br>
        <select id="ddlViewBy"  name="repetition[]" onChange="onChange(this)">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
</div>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="save-multiple-data">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When you click ADD button as indicated above, it duplicates the above form using this Javascript code:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.remove-btn', function() {
    $(this).closest('.main-form').remove();
});
    $(document).on("click", ".add-more-form", function() {
        $('.paste-new-forms').append('
        <div class="container-fluid main-form mt-3 border-bottom">\
            <div class="row">\
                <div class="col7">\
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">\
                        <label>Select Repetition</label> <br>\
                        <select id="ddlViewBy" name="repetition[]" onChange="onChange(this)">\
                            <option value="1">1</option>\
                            <option value="2">2</option>\
                            <option value="3">3</option>\
                            <option value="4">4</option>\
                            <option value="5">5</option>\
                        </select>\
                        <button onClick="onUnClick()" type="button" class="btn-danger">X</button>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
    });
});
</script>
```

The challenge:
After duplicating the form, I need the total count of values selected in dropdowns inside the select boxes for all duplicate forms. The total.

Right now, what I have achieved is basically getting the value of each dropdown which displays inside the `<p class="request"> </p>` above. The moment I select a value for another dropdown, the count changes to the current value of new dropdown instead of summing up the value of all of them. So I am basically getting the value of a single dropdown instead of the total sum in all dropdowns. How can I get the total count?

Comment: can you provide a JS Fiddle?

Comment: In the statement, "document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks + Number(elem.value); ", where is the variable "clicks" gets defined or assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that I found was to store the value of each dropdown in a global variable, so supposing that you don't want to increase the value if the same dropdown is selected twice, you can do the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <! –– Include this property with false as default when generating your dropdown ––>
  <select onChange="onChange(this)">
    <option value="default" selected disabled hidden>Choose a value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  
  <select onChange="onChange(this)">
    <option value="default" selected disabled hidden>Choose a value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  
  <select onChange="onChange(this)">
    <option value="default" selected disabled hidden>Choose a value</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <p>Current selection <a id="clicks"></a></p>
    <p>Total:  <a id="total">0</a></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button onClick="resetTotal()">reset total value</button>
  </div>
</body>

  <script>
    // global variable
    let totalValue = 0
    
    function onChange(elem) { 
      const select = elem
      
      // sum the value
      totalValue += Number(select.value)
      // update the DOM
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Number(totalValue);
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = Number(select.value);
      // disable selection, so you don't sum the same dropdown twice.
      select.disabled = true
    };

    // reset to default after selecting all dropdowns
    function resetTotal() {
      totalValue = 0;
      const selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select")
      
      for(let i=0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        // set selected option to default
        selects.item(i).selectedIndex = 0
        selects.item(i).disabled = false
      }
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = Number(totalValue);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you are right I don't want to increase the value if the same dropdown is selected twice. The issue I am seeing is however not getting the right Totals when you change the values from the original ones. It appears to only get the Total correct in the first instance.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I changed the things a bit so now I think it's working fine.

Comment: Still the same. The count stops working after changing values for all three dropdowns once. Any changes to any boxes don't change the result which means it's not working well.

Comment: Ok, probably I made the things very counter intuitive for you, as I said before, after selecting a dropdown you can't change his value again, so that's the reason why it's not working after selecting the three dropdowns, you should reset the value. Anyway, now I'm disabling each dropdown after a selection, so maybe it's more intuitive that way.